# Error in topsis(d, w, i) : 'decision' must be a matrix or data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, type-conversion

I am doing a TOPSIS analysis with R using [`topsis`](https://rdrr.io/cran/topsis/man/topsis.html).

For that, I started by importing the data.

As it was a table, and topsis requires the decision to be a matrix or a datafram, I have proceeded to convert it to a df as follows

```
data.df <- as.data.frame(data)
```

Or

```
data.df <- data.frame(data)
```

And indeed gives what one is looking for

```
>>> str(data.df)
'data.frame':   225 obs. of  2 variables:
$ time: int  6 6 7 7 6 7 6 7 8 7 ...
$ MAE  : num  5.43 5.63 5.35 5.48 5.62 5.48 5.53 5.43 5.24 5.42 ...
```

However, when I run

```
d <- data.df
w <- c(1, 1)
i <- c("-", "-")
topsis(d, w, i)
```

I am getting the following error

> Error in topsis(d, w, i) : 'decision' must be a matirx or data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a something related with the way the library is reading the df, as when I converted it to a matrix

```
data.df <- as.matrix(data)
```

It worked well.